# Angular - Select many images in Telegram Mini Apps

Tags: angular, typescript, telegram

I have a button to select multiple images `multiple="multiple"`
Selecting multiple images works everywhere, in all browsers. But it doesn’t work in Telegram Mini Apps on the phone https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps. Selecting multiple images works in Telegram for desktop computers, but does not work in Mini Apps on the phone.

I'm talking about multiple. If you select one image at a time, it works.

I don't know what the reason is.

**html**

```
    <input type="file" (change)="selectFiles($event)" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" ultiple="multiple">
```

**TypeScript**

```
    export class AddFormComponent {

        selectFiles(event?: any) {

            console.log(event.target.files.length)  // 0 or event>0

        } 

    }
```

Please tell me what is the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: The reason that selecting multiple images does not work in Telegram Mini Apps on the phone is because Telegram Mini Apps are based on WebAssembly, and WebAssembly does not currently support the multiple attributes on the input type="file" element. This is a known issue, and the Telegram team is working on a fix.